# How to parse apache solr database

Tags: parsing, hadoop, solr, nutch

I am using apache solr 4.10. Its data is provided via crawling by apache nutch (hadoop,hbase system). Solr is using local file system for its index storage. Now I have to parse and remove some bad documents i.e. documents that do not have content etc.

How I can parse it. Is there any way to use hadoop mapreduce for this purpose ?

Comment: A simple MR job can read the data, filter bad records and index them to the solr.

Comment: But solr index is in local file system not on hdfs ?

Comment: That is fine. You can send the data to solr for indexing. it need not to be on HDFS. Just point to the right Solr url. The hadoop cluster and solr machines should have connectivity.

Comment: Can you give me a reference or example about it. ?

Comment: Do you find some solution, if yes then please update answer ?